# Turn off message pane in Thunderbird

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird

I am using `Thunderbird 24.2.0`.I don't like message pane so every time when I open Thunderbird I just uncheck message pane from view > layout menu and it goes off. However when I restart (or start next time) the Thunderbird it turns on automatically.

Is there any way to turn off the message pane permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [gartenzaun](https://superuser.com/users/306070/gartenzaun)
suggested there was something wrong with my profile. I deleted my both accounts (profiles) from thunderbird (gmail and yahoo) after that I created new profile(s). and now the problem has gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you drag the splitter between the messages and the message pane all the way down, the message pane disappears. I just tried this myself and it stayed hidden after a restart.

I found the answer here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Window_layout_-_Thunderbird#Message_pane

> To resize the message pane, drag its splitter up or down
>   If you drag the splitter down, making the message pane too short, the pane suddenly collapses. This is useful when you do not need the message pane. The splitter remains at the bottom of the window:

Comment: I did that it is same as first one. Message pane still turns on automatically.

Comment: Then there might be something wrong with your profile. If you have any addons installed, could you try starting Thunderbird in safe mode? (Help --> Restart with addons disabled) If it works in safe mode, try enabling one addon at a time to figure out which one is causing the problems. If not, you might have to create a new profile.